# Derivation of a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

We consider the distribution

$$T(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)|\cos(x)|dx\quad\quad\forall \phi\in D(\mathbb{R})$$

Could you please help me to find the expressions of the derivatives $T^{(k)}$ for all $k\ge 1$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, derivatives of distributions are defined by duality.

$T'(\phi)=(T', \phi) = (-1)\cdot (T, \phi') = (-1) \int_\mathbb{R} \phi'(x) \vert \cos(x)\vert dx$.

Try to use integration by parts now!

Comment: the problem is that $x\mapsto |cos(x)|$ does not have a deravative when $x=k\pi$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Could you please hel me more. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but it is only in a countable set of points. So just split the integral up in chunks $\lbrack k \pi, (k+1) \pi \rbrack $. Do integration by parts in each chunk and recollect.

Comment: this is what i can write $$T'(\pi)=-\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\phi'(x)|cos(x)|dx$$ But i am blocked here

Comment: @lemmatheorem. Use intervals $[k\pi-\pi/2, (k+1)\pi-\pi/2]$ instead. On such an interval $\cos(x)$ has constant sign and you can write $|\cos(x)| = (-1)^{k} \cos(x).$ Then just do an integration by parts on each interval.